# Troubleshooting boot issues

Tags: centos, boot, troubleshooting

Server was running on Centos7 and it suddenly stopped responding. We tried rebooting and it is not able to find any OS to boot.

We have tried the following troubleshooting.

1. Tested ram using memtest, run for 48 hours and found no errors.
2. BIOS reset to optimal defaults.
3. Unable to boot into rescue mode using Centos7/8. It says `/bin/sh /usr/sbin/sulogin no such file or directory`
4. Unable to install Centos7/8, it does not even start the installation process, it just stops while starting up. [image]
5. Tried booting with Centos live disk, unable to start and it also hangs in the middle of booting up.
6. Booted with SystemRescueCD, fsck found no errors, tried mounting partitions and partitions seemed ok.

How to troubleshoot this further?